# Force Winform program to run at 96dpi?

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseevent, dpi

I currently have a winform application that relies relatively heavily on reading mouse click points. It's a video application that allows the user to click on incoming video feed from a webcam and draw lines on it and do other things. The important part for this question is the drawing lines- a simple example is that if they click somewhere on the video feed, it instantly draws a horizontal line across the entire picture at the point of the mouse.

This works flawlessly on 96dpi, but when windows scales to 125% zoom (Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Display -> Medium - 125%), which scales it to 120 dpi, it all goes to pot. Suddenly the application reads the mouse as being clicked much farther down the picture than it actually is.

All I'm doing is pulling the exact location of the mouse upon mouseclick. It is literally as simple as

```
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(tmpImage))
            {
                g.DrawLine(new Pen(lineColor, lineWidth),
                           new Point(0, e.Location.X), new Point(tmpImage.Width,
                           e.Location.Y));
            }
```

In 96dpi, it draws exactly at the mouse. At 120dpi, it draws quite a bit south of the mouse. This is a huge problem for me.

Is there any way that I can either make my application constantly run at 96dpi, or some other solution to cause my application to work appropriately under the circumstances of 120+dpi?

Thank you!

Comment: I strongly recommend WPF if you need real resolution independence and DPI independence. The winforms `X,Y` approach is really limited when it comes to these kind of things, and you will have to resort to all sorts of horrible hacks to get that working properly.

Comment: Does your zoom enlarge the picture ? If yes, you maybe have to "calc out" the zoom factor.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have much of an option on the Winform aspect. This application is already finished and this is a late find bug (something I really hadn't accounted for!). 

@Alex- as best as I can tell, the image does not appear to be zoomed by the windows dpi increase.

Comment: Yes, please follow @HighCore advice. As a Windows user on a retina Macbook, I can tell you that programs that don't respect my DPI settings look absolutely horrendous.

Comment: @GGati you can create this functionality that adds a horizontal line when clicking the mouse (in a resolution independent manner) in 5 minutes in WPF, without having to deal with crappy `e.Graphics` stuff. Then you could integrate that into an existing winforms application via the `ElementHost` if you needed to. Let me know if you need a WPF example on how to draw lines on mouse click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [AutoScaleMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.autoscalemode.aspx) property. this is what you need.

By default `AutoScaleMode` is set to `AutoScaleMode.Font` typically in `*.designer.cs` Change that to `AutoScaleMode.None` for no scaling or you can use `AutoScaleMode.Dpi` with `AutoScaleDimensions`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

In order to force your application to run at 96 DPI write this into Form1_Load:

```
        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        if (g.DpiX != 96)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Your message.");
            this.Close();
        }
```